# If click Eyes icon Show/Hide password (QPushButton)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to create a function in a register and login form using `QLineEdit` to show and hide password if click a `QPushButton`. I'm a beginner in Python, I'm just trying to do it but it's very hard... My attempt is not good because if I click the eye button the password is shown, but if click again to hide it does not work.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QLineEdit
import sys
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, maxWidth=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('MainWindow.ui', self)

        self.eyepass_show()
        self.eyepass_hide()

        self.btn_show_pwd.clicked.connect(self.eyepass_hide)
        self.btn_show_pwd.clicked.connect(self.eyepass_show)

    def eyepass_show(self):
        self.line_password.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Normal)
        print('show pass')

    def eyepass_hide(self):
        self.line_password.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        print('hide pass')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

form password hide/show eye:
[image: form password hide/show eye]

is hiding password is show but if click again to hide not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating two separate methods as `eyepass_show` and `eyepass_hide`, you can create a single function and toggle the visibility. Also, you are trying to connect the same signal twice to two different methods by `self.btn_show_pwd.clicked.connect(self.eyepass_hide)`and `self.btn_show_pwd.clicked.connect(self.eyepass_show)`

Try something like this:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QLineEdit
import sys
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, maxWidth=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('MainWindow.ui', self)

        self.eyepass_show()
        self.eyepass_hide()
        self.btn_show_pwd.clicked.connect(self.toggleVisibility)
        
    def toggleVisibility(self):
        if self.line_password.echoMode()==QLineEdit.Normal:
            self.line_password.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        else:
            self.line_password.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Normal)

    #     self.btn_show_pwd.clicked.connect(self.eyepass_hide)
    #     self.btn_show_pwd.clicked.connect(self.eyepass_show)
    # 
    # def eyepass_show(self):
    #     self.line_password.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Normal)
    #     print('show pass')
    # 
    # def eyepass_hide(self):
    #     self.line_password.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
    #     print('hide pass')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to add a checkable QAction to the QLineEdit and connect to the `toggled` (or `triggered`) signal.

[image: password field with embedded button]

```
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, maxWidth=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('MainWindow.ui', self)

        icon = QtGui.QIcon('eye-icon.png')
        self.showPassAction = QtWidgets.QAction(icon, 'Show password', self)
        self.line_password.addAction(
            self.showPassAction, QtWidgets.QLineEdit.TrailingPosition)
        self.showPassAction.setCheckable(True)
        self.showPassAction.toggled.connect(self.showPassword)

    def showPassword(self, show):
        self.line_password.setEchoMode(
            QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Normal if show else QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
```

If you want to show the password only when the mouse is pressed, then don't connect to the `toggled` signal, but find the child QToolButton for that action and connect to the `pressed` and `released` instead. In this case, the action doesn't need to be checkable.

```
        self.line_password.addAction(
            self.showPassAction, QtWidgets.QLineEdit.TrailingPosition)
        showPassButton = self.line_password.findChild(QtWidgets.QAbstractButton)
        showPassButton.pressed.connect(lambda: self.showPassword(True))
        showPassButton.released.connect(lambda: self.showPassword(False))
```

Answer (score -1):

One of the great things about PyQt5 is that it will *automatically* connect signals to methods for you. If you have a button named `<mybutton>` and a method in your app named `on_<mybutton>_clicked`, the the loadUi will automatically connect. So the pattern is

```
on_<widget_name>_<signal>
```

If we apply this to your problem, you should make your show/hide button a toggle button. In Qt Designer, set the checkable property to True (or do `btn_show_pwd.clicked.setChecked(True)`)

The code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QLineEdit
import sys
#import pymysql
#pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, maxWidth=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('test1.ui', self)

        self.line_password.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)

    def on_btn_show_pwd_toggled(self, checked):
        if checked:
            self.line_password.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        else:
            self.line_password.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Normal)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```